# expand and collapse icon in jQuery tree view is not shown in tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree-search

I designed jQuery tree view using [this](http://techlister.com/jquery/creating-jquery-tree-view-without-plugin/976/) web page. I changed this code little bit more.I removed the content of ' div class="tree" ' and add its content as follows.

```html
<div class="tree">
  
   <ul id="list">
  
        <div id="1">
     <li id="li_1"><a>2015/01/01 08:00:00</a>
      <ul id="ul_1">
                <div id="1_1"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:10:05 </a></li></div>
                <div id="1_2"><li id="T"><a>2015/01/01 08:15:10</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_3"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:27:15</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_4"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 08:39:20</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_5"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:46:25</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_6"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 08:55:30</a></li></div>
      </ul>
     </li>
        </div> 
        
        <div id="2">
      <li id="li_2"><a>2015/01/01 10:20:00 </a>
       <ul id="ul_2">
             <div id="2_1"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 10:28:09</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_2"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 10:37:20</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_3"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 10:45:13</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_4"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 10:48:26</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_5"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 10:57:54</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_6"><li id="T"><a>2015/01/01 11:12:00</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_7"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 11:20:09</a></li></div>
             <div id="2_8"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 11:28:12</a></li></div>
       </ul>
      </li>
        </div>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Tree view is worked successfully. But the expand/collapse icon(plus_minus icon) is not shown.Where am I wrong? Thanks for advices.

Comment: your code structure is wrong , ul may contain li  not the div, if you want to use div , use it inside <li><div></div></li>

Comment: But the tree expand and collapse finely. The issue is that it does not show the icon,Any suggestion for view icon without changing my code? Is it posible? I checked <li><div>...</div></li>, But nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

css looks for anchor under li of that ul but you inserted div there.that's why its not showing icon

```
.tree > ul > li > a {
color: #3B4C56;
display: block;
font-weight: normal;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none
```

icon's class>>

```
.tree li.parent > a:before {
background-image: url("../images/plus_minus_icons.png");
background-position: 25px center;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 21px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 23px;
```

Comment: But the tree expand and collapse finely. The issue is that it does not show the icon,Any suggestion for view icon without changing my code? Is it posible? I checked <li><div>...</div></li>, But nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.(Nishith Chaturvedi's advice is helpfull for me to build this answer.) First I changed the changing code little bit more again as follows.. :)

```css
.tree > .listClass > .testSuite > .testSuite_branch >a {
    color: #3B4C56;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tree > .listClass > .testSuite > .testSuite_branch >a:before {
    background-image: url("../images/plus_minus_icons.png"); 
    background-position: 25px center;
     content: ""; 
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  
   <ul id="list" class="listClass">
  
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1" class="testSuite">
     <li id="li_1" class="testSuite_branch"><a>2015/01/01 08:00:00 </a>
      <ul id="ul_1">
                <div id="1_1"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:10:05</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_2"><li id="T"><a>2015/01/01 08:15:10</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_3"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:27:1</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_4"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 08:39:2</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_5"><li id="start"><a>2015/01/01 08:46:25</a></li></div>
                <div id="1_6"><li id="F"><a>2015/01/01 08:55:30</a></li></div>
      </ul>
     </li>
        </div> 
     </ul>
  </div>
```